# emulator-x86.exe stopped working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I run my project , pop up error

> emulator-x86.exe stopped working

I was try this but still error

> If you are getting emulator-x86.exe has stopped working Error means:
>   Try these two steps:
>
> 1. Change the resolution of the device 1280X800 to 800X600.
> 2. Reduce thesize of the Ram by 512 MB or less.

this my AVD setting

> Marshallow : API23 : ABIx86 : Target Android6 
>   5.4" 480x854_API_23 mdpi : Use Host GPU  
>   Memory 256MB : VMHeap 16MB : IntStorage 200MB : SDcard 100MB

Computer spesification

> Operating System :    Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit 
>  CPU :    Intel Core 2
>   Duo E6400 @ 2.13GHz   53 °C 
>   Conroe 65nm Technology 
>  RAM : 
>     2.00GB Dual-Channel DDR2 @ 333MHz (5-5-5-15)

Comment: did you have intel haxm installed? check if in bios you have v-tx enabled

Comment: Harm installed,  now working after uncheck Use Host GPU,  any suggestions? Thanks @piotrek1543

Comment: you're using windows, so please check if Hyper-V is enabled, if yes you must disable it: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/42041-hyper-v-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar problem to you in the past even though HAXM is installed and on, in the end its just down to your processor as it can't handle the emulator that well, you can debug/run your app on to an android phone or tablet. If you have either of these to hand you need to go to RUN ---> EDIT CONFIGURATIONS and change the target devices to 'USB device'. On the phone/ tablet you need to go in to developer options and turn on USB debugging, if this doesn't work check to see if you have the phones/tablets drivers installed. There are plenty of tutorials on youtube. Good Luck! :)

Comment: Thanks @c_dev,  not found MP driver

Comment: Have you got your phone's/tablet's drivers installed on the laptop?